# IF else condition in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to compile the stored procedure:

```
create 
procedure checkFroud2(code IN varchar2, p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_recordset FOR

if code='C' then 
select * from emp
//dbms_output.putline('this is if block')
else if code='F' then
dbms_output.putline('this is else block')
else
dbms_output.putline('last else')
end if;
end checkFroud2;
```

but this is showing compile time errors. Can anybody suggest where the problem is?

Comment: Why are you voting down? do you have any problem with question or answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE
PROCEDURE checkFroud2(
          code IN VARCHAR2,
          p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
     IF code='C' THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('this is if block');
     OPEN p_recordset FOR        
     SELECT * FROM emp;
     ELSIF code='F' THEN

     --you can open p_recordset with dummy as
     /*open p_recordset for select * from dual where 1 = 0; */
          dbms_output.put_line('this is else block');

     ELSE
     /*open p_recordset for select * from dual where 1 = 0; */
          dbms_output.put_line('last else');
     END IF;
END checkFroud2;
/

var o refcursor;
BEGIN
CHECKfroud2
('C',:o);

END;
/

PRINT O;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
The correct code is as follows:

create procedure checkFroud2(code IN varchar2, p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN p_recordset FOR

if code='C' then 
select * from emp
//dbms_output.putline('this is if block');
elsif code='F' then
dbms_output.putline('this is else block');
else
dbms_output.putline('last else');
end if;
end checkFroud2;
```

Answer (score 2):

`ELSE IF` doesn't exist use `ELSIF`, also remove `//` before `dbms_output.putline('this is if block')`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example in oracle 11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_EMP_CHECK 
(
  EMPNO1 IN NUMBER 
, EMPNO2 IN NUMBER 
) 
AS 
EMPONE_NOT_EXISTS EXCEPTION;
EMPTWO_NOT_EXISTS EXCEPTION;
BOTHEMP_NOT_EXISTS EXCEPTION;
EMPCOUNT1 NUMBER;
EMPCOUNT2 NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO EMPCOUNT1 FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=EMPNO1;
  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO EMPCOUNT2 FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=EMPNO2;
  BEGIN
  IF( EMPCOUNT1=0 AND EMPCOUNT2=0)THEN 
    RAISE BOTHEMP_NOT_EXISTS;
  ELSIF ( EMPCOUNT1=0) THEN 
    RAISE EMPONE_NOT_EXISTS;
   ELSIF ( EMPCOUNT2=0) THEN 
    RAISE BOTHEMP_NOT_EXISTS;
    dbms_output.put_line('ELSE BLOCK');
   END IF; 
  END;

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN EMPONE_NOT_EXISTS THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line('EMP One not exit');
  WHEN EMPTWO_NOT_EXISTS THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line('EMP two not exit');
  WHEN BOTHEMP_NOT_EXISTS THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line('both not exit');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
END PROC_EMP_CHECK;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ELSIF` instead of `ELSE IF`. By using `ELSE IF` you're opening up a new nested `IF`-block, which you're not closing.

Answer (score 0):

**Couple of errors:**
 1. Open record set for ??? For what?? 
 2. ELSIF and no ELSE IF
3. where is ;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CHECKFROUD2 ( CODE        IN   VARCHAR2,
                         P_RECORDSET         OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN P_RECORDSET FOR SELECT * FROM DUAL;

    IF CODE = 'C'
    THEN
        SELECT * FROM EMP;
    ELSIF CODE = 'F'
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE ( 'this is else block' );
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE ( 'last else' );
    END IF;
END CHECKFROUD2;
```