# Insert data with specific condition using Oracle procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, adempiere

I want to insert data from view to table by using Oracle Procedure.
The view is called `VW_INVPART`. The view consist of column from different tables:

```
(M_Product table)
AD_ORG_ID,
AD_Client_ID,
Name,
M_Product_ID,

(M_Storage table)
QtyOnHand,

(M_Replenish table)
level_min

(M_Product_PO table)
order_min
```

The table I want to insert is `M_RequisitionLine`.

My scenario is there's goods quantity which defined in `QtyOnHand`. `QtyOnHand` is dynamic so it can be changed depends on the logistic in-out process. then there's minimum level which is defined in `level_min`. When goods run out of stock, we can order it again and there's minimum order quantity which is defined in `order_min`.

So, when the amount of `QtyOnHand` is *less than* `level_min`, we can add data to column `Qty` in `M_RequisitionLine` in order to request stock. But there are minimum quantity to be put in `M_RequisitionLine.Qty` (`order_min`).

If `level_min - QtyOnHand <= Order_min`, then set `M_RequisitionLine.Qty` to `Order_min`. 
But, If `level_min - QtyOnHand >= Order_min`, then set `M_RequisitionLine.Qty` into the difference between `level_min` and `QtyOnHand`.

How can I make the procedure in the Oracle? I've tried arranged the code but still confused as I am newbie in Oracle SQL.

Comment: see [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833642/if-else-condition-in-sql-store-procedure) for adding conditions in oracle stored procedures.

Comment: Sound like you could need [max](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions085.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You could write this into a PL/SQL stored procedure in the following way by using case command.  Very basic example below. Keep in mind, I don't know what the entity relationships are for your tables or what their cadinality is, so a lot of what I did is based on singular value assumptions.  If the select data returns more than one row, you have to use oracle collections.

```
  Declare
  t  M_Storage.QtyOnHand%TYPE;
  v  M_Replenish.Level_min%TYPE;
  o  M_Product_PO.order_min%TYPE; 

Begin
SELECT QtyOnHand INTO t FROM M_Storage;
SELECT Level_min INTO v FROM M_Replenish;
SELECT Order_min INTO o FROM M_Product_PO;

CASE 
   When t-v <  o Then UPDATE M_RequisitionLine set qty = o;
   When t-v >= o then UPDATE M_RequisitionLine set qty = t-v;
END CASE;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality already exists in standard Adempiere.

For a product, define the *min, max & replenishment* rules on the *Replenish tab* of the *Product Window*.  On the *Purchasing tab*, of the same window, you can define, per Supplier the *Minimum Order Qty*.

Now, if you run the *Replenishment Report* under the *Material Management* menu, you can run the report and generate Purchase Orders to fulfill the replenishment based on the rules you defined and this will honour the minimum order quantity set on the *Purchasing tab*,

It's not a technical solution but it works.

Now if your needs were even more complex fulfilment method that the standard you could define a **custom** replenishment rule.  This is a simple java class that must implement the Interface org.compiere.util.ReplenishInterface and requires that you implement one function... getQtyToOrder.

Once you have your class defined you specify this class on the *Warehouse window*.

Now, on the *Product window->Replenish tab* you can select **Custom** as the *Replenish Type* and this class will be used to calculate the quantity to replenish.

This approach would be better as it maintains your ability to use any supported database rather than just Oracle.